# PHP (preg_replace) regex strip image sizes from filename

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm working on a open-source [plugin](https://github.com/Mecanik/cloudflare-image-resizing) for WordPress and frankly facing an odd issue.

Consider the following filenames:

```
/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2-800x600.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/cutlery-tray-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/custommade-wallet-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-800x800-1.jpg
```

The current regex I have:

```
(-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}){1}
```

This will remove both matches from the filename, for example *buddha_-800x600-2-800x600.jpg* will become *buddha_-2.jpg* which is invalid.

I have tried a variety of regex:

```
.*(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}) // will trip out everything
(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}){1}|.*(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}){1} // same as above
(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}){1}|(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}){1} // will strip out all size matches
```

Unfortunately my knowledge with regex is quite limited, can someone advise how to achieve the goal please?

The goal is to remove only what is relevant, which would result in:

```
/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/cutlery-tray-800x600-2.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/custommade-wallet-800x600-2.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-1.jpg
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why is in the last example `/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-1.jpg` the dimensions removed but in the first 3 examples the dimensions are reduced to 1 occurrence? Do you only want to remove duplicate dimension entries to a single occurrence, and if there already is a single occurrence remove that? You state `The goal is to remove only what is relevant,` but how to know what is relevant?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Because that's how the filenames are on the server, cropped filename example: "/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2-800x600.jpg", original: "/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2.jpg". Then, cropped filename: "/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-800x800-1.jpg", original: "/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-1.jpg". I just want to get rid of the size that wordpress added there, and get the original filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group with a backreference to match strings where there are 2 of the same parts and replace that with a single part.

Or match the dimensions to be removed.

```
((-\d+x\d+)-\d+)\2|-\d+x\d+
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(-\d+x\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match `-` 1+ digits `x` and 1+ digits
  - `-\d+` Match - and 1+ digits
- `)\2` Close group 2 followed by a backreference to what is captured in grouip 1
- `|` Or
- `-\d+x\d+` Match the dimensions format

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hi96dv/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rs5AA)

For example

```
$pattern = '~((-\d+x\d+)-\d+)\2|-\d+x\d+~';
$strings = [
    "/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2-800x600.jpg",
    "/wp-content/uploads/cutlery-tray-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg",
    "/wp-content/uploads/custommade-wallet-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg",
    "/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-800x800-1.jpg",
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    echo  preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $s) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/cutlery-tray-800x600-2.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/custommade-wallet-800x600-2.jpeg
/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I guess I had poor regex and missing '$1' as replacement.

Comment: Sorry, I rushed accepting the answer without testing properly. It seems it still breaks some images, for example: "/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/buddha_-800x600-2-768x576.jpg", it will remove "-768x576" (which is OK) but it will also remove "-800x600", making the image not found.

Comment: @Mecanik Hi there, in that case you can change `\2` to `(?2)` like `((-\d+x\d+)-\d+?)(?2)|-\d+x\d+`  See https://regex101.com/r/yD2Yqz/1

Comment: Thanks! It works great now. Hopefully will remain the same :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. You can test it yourself. Here is the code:

```
$a = [
     '/wp-content/uploads/buddha_-800x600-2-800x600.jpg',
     '/wp-content/uploads/cutlery-tray-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg',
     '/wp-content/uploads/custommade-wallet-800x600-2-800x600.jpeg',
     '/wp-content/uploads/UI-paths-800x800-1.jpg'
];
            
foreach($a as $img) 
    echo preg_replace('#-\d+x\d+((-\d+|)\.[a-z]{3,4})#i', '$1', $img).'<br>';
```

It checks for ending -(number)x(number)(dot)(extension)

Comment: Thanks, but please read my question again. In your regex the filename UI-paths-800x800-1.jpg is not processed due to extra stuff after the size.

Comment: Regex corrected. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, nearly there! It seems to work, but some images still fail. I will get back after more testing.

Answer (score -1):

This is a clear case of « Match the rejection, revert the match ».
So, you just have to think about the pattern you are searching to remove:

```regex
[0-9]+x[0-9]+
```

which is simply (much condensed):

```
\d+x\d+
```

The next step is to build the groups extractor:

```regex
^(.*[^0-9])[0-9]+x[0-9]+([^x]*\.[a-z]+)$
```

We added the extension of the file as a suffix for the extract.
The rejection of the "x" char is a (bad…) trick to ensure the match of the *last* size only. It won’t work in the case of an alphanumeric suffix between the size and the extension (`toto-800x1024-ex.jpg` for instance).

And then, the replacement string:

```regex
$1$2
```

For clarity of course, we are only working on a successfully extracted filename. But if you want to treat the whole string, the pattern becames:

```regex
^/(.*[^0-9])[0-9]+x[0-9]+([^/x]*\.[a-z]+)$
```

If you want to split the filename and the folder name:

```regex
^/(.*/)([^/]+[^0-9])[0-9]+x[0-9]+([^/x]*)(\.[a-z]+)$
^/(.*/)([^/]+\D)\d+x\d+([^/x]*)(\.[a-z]+)$
```

```perl
$folder=$1;
$filename="$1$2";
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice explanation, however can you give me a working example of preg_replace please?

Comment: Uhh ?
man preg_replace indicates:
preg_replace('@pattern@', 'replacement', $string) --> preg_replace('@^/(.*/)([^/]+)[0-9]+x[0-9]+([^/x]*)(\.[a-z]+)$@i,'$1$2$3',$wholename);
i is a modifier that means “case insensitive”.

Comment: You don’t have to be rude to be smart, especially when somebody is trying to answer to a question you asked.
Add a [^0-9] in the start pattern will solve your “completely wrong (!)” problem.
I have fixed my answer.